# Airflow: Pull XCom from DAG with a future start date?

Tags: airflow

In Airflow, we use xcoms to signal that one DAG has finished and another can start running. E.g. DAG 1 runs at 12 AM and sends an xcom when it's done. DAG 2 reads the xcom from DAG 1.

One limitation of using this is that per the documentation -- xcom's can only read from DAGs with an earlier execution date, but cannot read from DAGs with a future execution date. https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/_modules/airflow/models/xcom.html

For the sake of an example, let's say I have 4 DAGS, DAG #1, #2, #3, #4 that all do something. Then I have DAG #5 which can run several jobs in parallel. DAG#5 relies on DAGS #1-4 for different reason and has separate checks for each of them. The DAGS are scheduled as follows:

DAG #1: 12 AM
DAG #2: 12 AM
DAG #3: 12 AM
DAG #4: 2 AM
DAG #5: 1 AM

DAG #5 has 4 tasks that are essentially utilizing the `airflow.models.xcom.get_one` method to read the XCcom from DAGS#1-4. But since DAG #4 has a start time of 2 AM, DAG #5 cannot read from DAG #4.

Is there a way to get around this? The only thing considered so far is simply scheduling DAG #4 earlier and having it sleep for an hour, but that doesn't seem like a good practice.

Comment: You may want to take a look at TriggerDagRunOperator
https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/_modules/airflow/operators/dagrun_operator.html

Answer (score 0):

Airflow has a concept of sensors. Sensors are used to test for some condition before the DAG execution continues. In your case, you could use the [ExternalTaskSensor](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/_api/airflow/sensors/external_task_sensor/index.html#airflow.sensors.external_task_sensor.ExternalTaskSensor): DAG 5 would have four such sensors sensing for success of DAGs 1, 2, 3, and 4. You will not need XCOM in this case at all.

Some more info about [cross-DAG dependencies.](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/howto/operator/external.html#cross-dag-dependencies)